# trying to create form validation

Tags: javascript, validation

trying to create form validation to validate so that only alphanumeric characters will be allowed to submit using javascript but nothings working and i dont know what to do next, no jquery just plain js

```
function validate() {
'use strict';
var errMsg = "";
var result = true;

var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;

if (!fname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "Alphanumeric Characters only\n";
    result = false;
}
if (errMsg !== "") {
    alert(errMsg);
}
return result;
}
function init() {
var enquiries = document.getElementById('enquiries').value;
enquiries.onsubmit = validate;
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Show us your HTML or create a JSFiddle. Is your console showing any errors? Are you getting any `alert` boxes at all?

Comment: Have you ever tried input pattern tag?

Comment: HTML + js fiddle  will help us fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
var enquiries = document.getElementById('enquiries').value;
enquiries.onsubmit = validate;
```

`.onsubmit` is being assigned to the value of the enquiries element, rather than the element itself. If you remove `.value`, your code should work.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SL7lZzLSje7BEuDRttym?p=preview